# Matrix does not save values

Tags: matrix

So I have this field created for one of my users in which I use matrix. EE is version 2.7 and matrix is 2.5.9 I also use MSM

So, basically there is a grid with 2 columns, one is for names and other is for sound. I upload mp3 file, that works ok, I go to matrix field, click add file, I see it, click save and then file is gone. I can do that forever. Like it does not sees change in value.

I have another entry, where also I have sounds, but that entry is few months old. there i click save, everything stays same. It does not delete values.

As far as I see it, problem is in Matrix fieldtype.

Comment: What kind of columns are these? File field? Assets?

Comment: Actually I am trying to save file value. in Matrix one cell is text other cell is file. File cell cannot save value

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade to Matrix 2.5.10. According to the [release notes for that version](https://docs.pixelandtonic.com/matrix/changelog.html):

> Fixed a PHP error that would prevent File cells from saving properly.

Comment: Great. I love upgrade process. So I have to upgrade EE but when I tried it i cannot login back to administration because of errors. Probably some module is making a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had to switch to grid from ellislab. Now i do not have any problems. I did upgrade of matrix but it was easier to change then to wait to repair problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem a few months back. See post here: [Images disappearing from Matrix field](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/8815/images-disappearing-from-matrix-field/21247#21247)

Upgrading to the newest version of Matrix was the ticket for me.